# Android: Play mutilple files on after other using MediaPlayer

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play several mediafiles one after another using `MediaPlayer`. The directory from which I am trying to play files has about 20 files, the code which I have written plays three files only and then stop playing. Please point my mistake and help me in solving it.

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        System.out.println("coming here to playNextMEdia");
                        playNextMedia();
                    }    
                });
            }

private void playNextMedia() {
        System.out.println("playNextMedia "+files.size()+"and"+counter );
        if(counter<files.size()){
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.fromFile(files.get(counter)));

            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    System.out.println("playNextFile() cehck 1");

                    //playNextFile();
                    //System.out.println("playNextFile() cehck 2");
counter++;
                    playNextMedia();
                }

            });
```

**Logcat**

```
10-09 21:49:10.129: I/System.out(2644): coming here to playNextMEdia
10-09 21:49:10.129: I/System.out(2644): playNextMedia 19and1
10-09 21:49:36.249: I/System.out(2644): playNextFile() cehck 1
10-09 21:49:36.249: I/System.out(2644): playNextMedia 19and2
```

Probably, I am missing a small condition check or something.

**Edit 1**

```
if (fd != null) {
                try { 
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fd);
                    //mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.fromFile(files.get(counter)));  
                    mediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);


                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {  
                    e.printStackTrace();  

                } catch (IOException e) {  
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                }  
                mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Instead of using `create()` to create new MediaPlayers all the time, I would use setDataSource: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(java.lang.String)

Comment: @KenWolf I have tried using setDataSource also & resetting mediaPlayer also, its not doing any good

Comment: Where do you call `.start()`?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure where this happens in relation to your other block of code. Anyway, you need to call `prepare()` after `setDataSource()`, as a side note.

Comment: yeah, I am calling `prepare()` before `start()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        counter++;
        if (counter < files.size()) {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(files.get(counter));
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }    
});
```